# Unclear compiler error after implementing a change in a structure using forward declarations

Tags: c, xc8

I believed that the strange behaviour of the XC8 compiler was due to problems with forward declarations. With help of you all I have corrected that but the strange error remains.  So now I elaborate a little more on my problem.
In the MENU structure CursorStr has been implemented and gives trouble.
If I take out CursorStr and use the ButtonFunc* directly then all goes well.
Below the structs I have included the #define statements used througout the program.

```
typedef struct ArrowStr {
    // Cursor select data
    uint8_t UP[4];
    uint8_t DOWN[4];
    uint8_t RIGHT[4];
    uint8_t LEFT[4];
}ARROW_STR;

typedef struct MenuStr MenuStr;
typedef uint8_t ButtonFunc(MenuStr *);

typedef struct CursorStr
{         
    ButtonFunc* ButtonUpPtr;
    ButtonFunc* ButtonDownPtr;
    ButtonFunc* ButtonLeftPtr;
    ButtonFunc* ButtonRightPtr;
    ButtonFunc* PreMenuCursorPtr;
    ButtonFunc* MenuCursorPtr;
    ButtonFunc* PostMenuCursorPtr;
}CURSOR_STR;

typedef struct MenuStr
{
    ARROW_STR Arrows; 
    // not known anymore
    int    *ValueArray;
    // Cusor position data
    uint8_t ROW_POS[4];
    uint8_t COL_POS[4];
    // A5-A3 format strings
    uint8_t Format[3][3];
    INDEX ROW_INDEX;
    INDEX COL_INDEX;
    INDEX DIM_INDEX;
    INDEX EDIT_INDEX;

    INDEX FORMAT_INDEX;
    uint8_t CURRENT_MENU;
    CURSOR_STR CursorStr;

  //  ButtonFunc* ButtonUpPtr;
  //  ButtonFunc* ButtonDownPtr;
  //  ButtonFunc* ButtonLeftPtr;
   // ButtonFunc* ButtonRightPtr;
   // ButtonFunc* PreMenuCursorPtr;
  //  ButtonFunc* MenuCursorPtr;
  //  ButtonFunc* PostMenuCursorPtr;
    uint8_t CursorX;
    uint8_t CursorY;
}MENU;

// used in case of CursorStr
    #define pButtonDownPtr       Menu->CursorStr.ButtonDownPtr
    #define pButtonUpPtr         Menu->CursorStr.ButtonUpPtr
    #define pButtonLeftPtr       Menu->CursorStr.ButtonLeftPtr
    #define pButtonRightPtr      Menu->CursorStr.ButtonRightPtr
    #define pPreMenuCursorPtr    Menu->CursorStr.PreMenuCursorPtr
    #define pMenuCursorPtr       Menu->CursorStr.MenuCursorPtr
    #define pPostMenuCursorPtr   Menu->CursorStr.PostMenuCursorPtr
    #define pCursorPtrs          Menu->CursorStr

 // used directly   
    #define pButtonDownPtr       Menu->ButtonDownPtr
    #define pButtonUpPtr         Menu->ButtonUpPtr
    #define pButtonLeftPtr       Menu->ButtonLeftPtr
    #define pButtonRightPtr      Menu->ButtonRightPtr
    #define pPreMenuCursorPtr    Menu->PreMenuCursorPtr
    #define pMenuCursorPtr       Menu->MenuCursorPtr
    #define pPostMenuCursorPtr   Menu->PostMenuCursorPtr
```

In XC8 all compiles and runs fine with the direct approach but with the CursorStr approach a declaration conflict (1098) is reported. Of course I can reach my goal in using some calls to save, store and replace the pointers but I would like to see the CursorStr approach working because that would keep the code more simple. Again help is appreciated.

**Addition:**

If

```
typedef uint8_t ButtonFunc(MenuStr *)
```

is changed into

```
typedef uint8_t ButtonFunc(uint8_t *)
```

then I get understandably all kinds of warnings but the code compiles and the program works. So there must be still something with the forward declaration.

**Addition2**

Since I could not get what I wanted I created a workaround and changed the MENU_STR into the code below. This works without any error or warning. So for the moment I think that the problem comes from the XC8 compiler.

```
typedef uint8_t ButtonFunc(struct MenuStr *);
typedef uint8_t CursorFunc(void *);

 typedef struct Buttons{
       CursorFunc* ButtonUpPtr;
       CursorFunc* ButtonDownPtr;
       CursorFunc* ButtonLeftPtr;
       CursorFunc* ButtonRightPtr;
       CursorFunc* PreMenuCursorPtr;
       CursorFunc* MenuCursorPtr;
       CursorFunc* PostMenuCursorPtr;   
   }BUTTONS;


typedef struct MenuStr
{
    ARROW_STR Arrows; 
    // not known anymore
    int    *ValueArray;
    // Cusor position data
    uint8_t ROW_POS[4];
    uint8_t COL_POS[4];
    // A5-A3 format strings
    uint8_t Format[3][3];
    INDEX ROW_INDEX;
    INDEX COL_INDEX;
    INDEX DIM_INDEX;
    INDEX EDIT_INDEX;

    INDEX FORMAT_INDEX;
    uint8_t CURRENT_MENU;

    union
    {
         BUTTONS ButtonsPtrs;    
         struct 
         {
                 ButtonFunc* ButtonUpPtr;
                 ButtonFunc* ButtonDownPtr;
                 ButtonFunc* ButtonLeftPtr;
                 ButtonFunc* ButtonRightPtr;
                 ButtonFunc* PreMenuCursorPtr;
                 ButtonFunc* MenuCursorPtr;
                 ButtonFunc* PostMenuCursorPtr;   
        };
    };
    uint8_t CursorX;
    uint8_t CursorY;
}MENU;
```

Comment: What is `typedef uint8_t ButtonFunc(MenuStr *);` supposed to be?

Comment: What's the exact compiler error message? Can't reproduce, your code compiles cleanly on all mainstream compilers.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It's a typedef of a function pointer, which doesn't hide the `*` behind a typedef.

Comment: @Lundin Pls see the addition on the question.

Comment: "a declaration conflict (1098) is reported" ... on which specific source line?

Comment: The declaration conflict is reported on  the function uint8_t MenuButtons(MENU *Menu). in the header file and the code file. As far as i can see there is no correlation between the error other than the fact that the MENU structure is used,

Comment: Yes well, I tried the code posted here in numerous mainstream compilers, only adding `#include <stdint.h>` and a typedef for INDEX. It compiles cleanly even with high warning levels set, on gcc, clang, icc. Even on MSVC. So either the problem is related to the file structure of your project, or the infamous Microchip compiler or this isn't the actual code.

Comment: @Lundin I have created a functional workaround compiling and linking without a problem. See addition 2

Comment: It's a weird problem, maybe related to the various stack tricks specific to PIC, or maybe related to how their compiler changes pointer sizes dynamically depending on use etc. I peeked at the MPLAB manual but nothing in its documentation about deviations from the standard mentions struct forward declarations. I'd open a support ticket with Microchip and give them a project that reproduces the error.

Comment: @Lundin I am going to follow your advise

Comment: Which version of XC8 are you using.  The original code compiles on  version 1.42.  At a guess it is your use of **typedef struct MenuStr MenuStr**.  Try changing it to **typedef struct MenuStr MENU**.

Comment: @cup I tried on 1.45; 2.00 and 2.05. I keep your comment in mind.

Comment: @Decapod did you get this resolved - having the same issue right now.